# SFMC Custom Activity - Clicking on a step always acts as the final step

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I'm currently in the midst of building my first Custom Activity. Things are going pretty well, but I'm noticing an issue where if I navigate to a step by clicking on it, the Custom Activity configuration wizard acts like I clicked on the last step. Is this expected, or am I missing something?

My Configuration JS, minus some sensitive information, is below. Before that I wanted to note two things:

1. I am adding more steps after the first step completes. Even when I removed this I noticed the same issue.
2. From doing some deep debugging of the JS, it seemed like the step click event was firing twice for me.

```javascript
define([], function () {
  return {
    "key": "[key]",
    "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
    "metaData": {
      "icon": "images/icon.png",
      "iconSmall": "images/iconSmall.png",
      "category": "message",
      "expressionBuilderPrefix": "[prefix]",
      "isConfigured": false,
      "configurationDisabled": false,
      "configOnDrop": true
    },
    "type": "REST",
    "lang": {
      "en-US": {
        "name": "[CustomActivityName]",
        "description": "["Description]"
      }
    },
    "arguments": {
      "execute": {
        "inArguments": [],
        "outArguments": [],
        "url": "[url]",
        "useJwt": true
      }
    },
    "configurationArguments": {
      "applicationExtensionKey": "[key]",
      "publish": {
          "url": "[url]",
          "useJwt": true
      }
    },
    "wizardSteps": [
      {
        "label": "Select Template",
        "key": "selectTemplate"
      },
      {
        "label": "Map Fields",
        "key": "mapFields"
      },
      {
        "label": "Confirm",
        "key": "confirm"
      },
    ],
    "userInterfaces": {
      "configModal": {
        "width": 700,
        "height": 480,
        "fullscreen": false,
        "url": "[url]/"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Spot an error in your config.json file, you have a comma after the last object of wizardSteps array, it should be removed.

[image]

2. Check the **onClickedNext** function in *customActivity.j*s file

if "confirm" is the last step, you should have something like this

```
function onClickedNext () {
        if (currentStep.key === 'confirm'
        ) {
            save();
        } else {
            connection.trigger('nextStep');
        }
    }
```

3. also worth checking the beginning of *customActivity.js* file, steps array should have the same values as your *config.json* file

   ```
   'use strict';

   var connection = new Postmonger.Session();
   var payload = {};
   var lastStepEnabled = false;
   var steps = [ // initialize to the same value as what's set in config.json for consistency
       {
          "label": "Select Template",
          "key": "selectTemplate"
       },
       {
          "label": "Map Fields",
          "key": "mapFields"
       },
       {
          "label": "Confirm",
          "key": "confirm"
       }
   ];
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion here and identifying that i had the extra comma. Unfortunately just changing that didn't seem to make a difference. The issue I'm seeing seems to be coming from something with the click event in JavaScript.